# contact form php help

Tags: php, contacts

Ok I have our contact form fully working, and processing correctly. I have two questions ...

1. on the contact form page , I wish to add a checkbox for user to tick to send copy of the email to them aswell.
2. on the process form part I want to redirect to error page if all goes horribly wrong.

Currently on my form submit i have action going to thankyou.php

My form process i have added within the thankyou.php page but could pull it out separately if needed.

.......................................

My form process is below ( very very simple )

```
<?php

$youremail = "someonesemail@email.com";

$yourname    = $_POST['yourname'];
$email   = $_POST['email'];
$location = $_POST['location'];
$textarea = $_POST['textarea'];

 $headers = "From: $email";

$content = "Hello there! This is a message from your contact form.\r\n
\r\n
\r\n
Name: $yourname\r\n
\r\n
E-mail: $email\r\n
\r\n
Location: $location\r\n
\r\n
Message: $textarea\r\n\r\n";

$send = mail($youremail, 'Message from your conatct form', $content, $headers);

 if($send)
 {
echo "ok";
 }
```

Im not brill with php so any help appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$youremail  = "someonesemail@email.com";
$yourname   = $_POST['yourname'];
$email      = $_POST['email'];
$location   = $_POST['location'];
$textarea   = $_POST['textarea'];
$ReceiveMail= $_POST['txtReceive'];

if($ReceiveMail == "yes") {
    $content    = "";
    $headers    = "From: $email";
    @mail($email, 'Mail Notification', $content, $headers);
}
    $headers    = "From: $email";
    $content = "Hello there! This is a message from your contact form.\r\n
    \r\n
    \r\n
    Name: $yourname\r\n
    \r\n
    E-mail: $email\r\n
    \r\n
    Location: $location\r\n
    \r\n
    Message: $textarea\r\n\r\n";
    $send = mail($youremail, 'Message from your conatct form', $content, $headers);
    if($send)    {
        header("location:thankyou.php");
        exit;
    }
    else {
        header("location:error.php");
        exit;
    }
?>
```

I have added one checkbox in form and check the value in server side.
Try this. Hope it will help

Answer (score 1):

If you want to send copy of mail, then you need to add proper headers for mail, like:

```
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'To: Somename <some_email@example.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Cc: '.$yourCopyMail . "\r\n"; // this is for copy
//then
if(mail(....)) {
  echo "sent";
}
else {
  header("Location: url_to_your_error_page");
  exit;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Sudhir, I was looking at else goto, ... couldnt figure it out. Will give that a whirl thankyou

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your first question:

[This page](http://www.html-form-guide.com/php-form/php-form-checkbox.html) gives a quick tutorial on how to add a checkbox to your form and receive the value on the following page. When you're processing the form submission, just look at the variable `$_POST["checkboxname"]` and see if it's set to the value you gave to the checkbox (or if it's set at all, really). If it is, then just repeat the command to send the email, with the user's email as the recipient.

In your case it looks like that would be `$send = mail($email, 'Message from your conatct form', $content, $headers);`

I don't know how to answer your second question, because "if all goes horribly wrong" isn't a particularly meaningful conditional.